# diy comment remover not working, what am i doing wrong? (Invalid read of size 1, segfault)

Tags: c

Here is the code and valgrind report. What am I doing wrong? This is code for comment remover written in C. I tried to look former threads about invalid read size and segfault, but I didn't really get the hang of my problem. I know I malloc too much memory if any comments are removed, but I don't think that should cause problems should it?

edit: If you need the main function which is used for testing this I can attach it too.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *delete_comments(char *input) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int a = 0;
    
    char* dest = malloc(    (strlen(input) + 1) * sizeof(char)  );
    
    while (i < strlen(input)) {
         if(input[i] == '/' && input[i + 1] == '/') {
            while (input[i - 1] != '\n') {
            }         
         }
         else if (input[i] == '/' && input[i+1] == '*') {
            while (input[i-1] != '*' || input[i] != '/') {
                i++;
            }
         }
    
         dest[a] = input[i];
         i++;
         a++;
    }
    
    free(input); 
    return dest;
}
```

Build log:

```
make -C test valgrind
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/agent/test'
sed -e 's/int[ \t]\{1,\}main[ \t]*[(]/int _no_main(/g;s/void[ \t]\{1,\}main[ \t]*[(]/void _no_main(/g;s/^main[ \t]*[(]/_no_main(/g' ../src/source.c >../src/source.c.nomain.c
gcc -pthread -g -Wall -Wvla -std=c99 -o test test_source.c tmc-check.c checkhelp.c ../src/source.c.nomain.c -lcheck_pic -pthread -lrt -lm -lsubunit
valgrind -q --log-file=valgrind.log --track-origins=yes --leak-check=yes ./test
Running suite(s): Test-08_cleaner
0%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1
test_source.c:67:E:test_delete_comments:test_delete_comments:0: (after this point) Received signal 11 (Segmentation fault)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/agent/test'

Valgrind output:
==44== Invalid read of size 1
==44==    at 0x402FB9: delete_comments (source.c.nomain.c:19)
==44==    by 0x401E3D: test_delete_comments (test_source.c:74)
==44==    by 0x406DE2: srunner_run (in /home/agent/test/test)
==44==    by 0x402492: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==44==    by 0x402127: main (test_source.c:206)
==44==  Address 0x105b3cc4f is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==44== 
==44== 
==44== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==44==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x105B3CC4F
==44==    at 0x402FB9: delete_comments (source.c.nomain.c:19)
==44==    by 0x401E3D: test_delete_comments (test_source.c:74)
==44==    by 0x406DE2: srunner_run (in /home/agent/test/test)
==44==    by 0x402492: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134)
==44==    by 0x402127: main (test_source.c:206)
==44==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==44==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==44==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==44==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==44==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 2048000
```

Comment: You have unsigned ints and when `i == 0`, `i - 1` is a very large number, probably 2³² − 1. (That would mean that your input starts with a `//` comment. The while loop in line 19 is also an infinite loop. And you probably shouldn't `free` the input in this function; let the caller do it.)

Comment: `while (i < strlen(input)) {`, seriously? You want to recalculate the length of the input string on every loop iteration? `unsigned int` should be replaced with `size_t` which is the appropriate type.

Comment: `while (input[i-1] != '*' || input[i] != '/') {
                i++;
            }` may access the array out of bounds

Comment: Please attached main function

Comment: You need an else before `dest[a] = input[i];` in case of two consecutive comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segfault occurs here:

```
while (input[i - 1] != '\n') ...
```

Your counter `i` is an unsigned int. At the beginning you have `i == 0` and  `i - 1` is a very large number, probably 2³² − 1. This might cause the segfault.

Note that Valgrind says that the address wasn't "stack'd, malloc'd". Usually, if you break the bounds of an array, it will say that the offending address is "one byte beyond malloc'd memory" or something similar.

Using unsigned ints as counters is a good choice, but be careful when you go backwards. In your case, you don't need to look backwards at all: You should advance beyond the `//` and then move forwards as long as required.

As an aside: Testing for `strlen()` in a loop condition is not a good idea in C, because `strlen` walks the whole string and looks for a null terminator. A smart compiler might optimize that, but it is better to calculate the string length once or, maybe better, test whether `input[i] != '\0'.

The terminating null is something you need to consider when skipping characters with a negated condition, too. For example, it is not enough to check whether the current character isn't a new-line. You must also make sure that it isn't the null terminator:

```
while (input[i] && input[i] != '\n') i++;
```

Comment: Thanks man! my code was too big to fit in a comment so would u mind checking it up if u got time, i posted it as an answer. Sorry im kinda new in stackoverflow so not sure if i could have done it in a better way.

Comment: oh it got deleted mb :( Do you know why it says this:

Answer (score 0):

You have a perpetual loop in

```
        while (input[i - 1] != '\n') {
        }
```

This is not going anywhere. You at least need to update the loop variable `i` in every iteration.